# What is the probability that he answers $4$ correct answers of the first $5$ questions?

Tags: probability

> We have a test of $10$ questions.
>   Suppose we have a student that answer $8$ correct answers. What is the probability that he answers $4$ correct answers of the first $5$ questions?
>   There isn't any connection between the questions in the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we already know that the student has answered correctly 8 questions, for him to answer $4$ correct answers in the $5$ first, he must have a mistake in the first $5$ ones, and another in the $5$ last ones. So there are, $5\times5=25$ ways to do this. The total number of ways to answer $8$ questions correctly in $10$ is $\binom{10}{8}=45$. Hence, the probability desired is
$$P=\frac{25}{45}=\frac{5}{9}$$

Comment: can you explain why ther are 25 ways to make 1 mistake in the first 5 and 1 mistake in the last 5? is it beacuse of (5 choose 4)*(5 choose 4)?

Comment: You have $5$ ways to pick a quesiton to make a mistake in the first $5$ ones, and $5$ ways to pick in the $5$ last ones. So, $5\times 5=25$

Comment: got it... thanks for the quick answer...